# npm ERR! invalid: minizlib@1.0.3

Tags: node.js

1. Pretty new to Node.
2. Was preparing to install Babel
3. So I checked to make sure I hadn't already installed it by running `npm list -g --depth=0`
4. Wherein I received this error message:

`npm ERR! invalid: minizlib@1.0.3 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minizlib`

How do I fix please? Thanks.

Linux 17.10

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I ran `sudo npm install -g npm@latest` to reinstall npm, then I ran `npm list -g --depth=0`

..and no more error!

Comment: Awesome. Same problem, fixed! :)

Comment: `sudo: npm: command not found`, for me it worked without `sudo`